# Does RichFaces or JSF have something like jscroll?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Need to implement a feature where auto suggest shows first 10 result, when user scrolls it fetches further 10 from server.

I have implemented auto suggest using rich faces `<rich:suggestionbox>` but it does not support paging or infinite scroll.

It would be great if someone can guide me with some JSF based component or way of customizing the existing suggestion box.

Comment: You need to upgrade your richfaces; the newer version, `<rich:autocomplete/>` provides lazy loading

Comment: It would be difficult to upgrade. Is it possible to combine jquery's jscroll with <rich:suggestionbox>